# Ratelimit for underlying service call not working in SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, rate-limiting, resilience4j

In my project, I have to ratelimit underlying service call, implemented a solution using resilliance4j, while doing performance testing with more number of users / load it is not rate limiting the underlying service call as expected. Sometimes, it triggering RequestNotPermitted but not most of the times and not limiting underlying calls as configured.

I am using Spring WebClient to make service call

My sample implementation looks like,

```
Class Test {

@Autowired
private ServiceRepository serviceRepository;


private List<Dto> testRateLimit(List<Object> list) {

return Flux.fromIterable(list).flatMap(o -> serviceRepository.underlyingServiceCall(o))
.doOnSucces(
//do something
)
.doOnError(
//log error message
)
.onErrorResume(
//do something
).collectList().block();
}

}


Class ServiceRepository { 

@Autowired
private WebClient webClient;

RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.of("test", 
                                         RateLimiterConfig
                                         .custom()
                                         .limitForPeriod(10)
                                         .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                                         .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(0)).build());


@TimeLimiter(name= "Test")
@CircuitBreaker(name= "Test")
private Mono<Dto> underlyingServiceCall(Object o) {

return webClient
       .post()
       .uri("xyz")
       .bodyValue(o)
       .doOnNext(a -> {
        // log message
     })
       .transform(RateLimiter.of(rateLimiter))

}

}
```

I have to allow only 10 calls per second to the underlying service,

For example,

thread 1 executing the method testRateLimit() with 6 object

thread 2 executing the method testRateLimit() with 8 object then the ratelimiter should restrict processing 4 objects from thread2.

To know whether it is working, I am using splunk query based on the log message which is printed inside doOnNext() in webclient implementation.

Your input will be helpful.